# Swift 3: Create UIImage from UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uibezierpath

I have a `UIBezierPath`, and I ultimately I need a `UIImageView` from it. Right now I'm trying to first create a `UIImage`, and then a `UIImageView` from that.

I'm working in swift, and I have looked at similar questions, and the answers either don't work or produce a shape rather than a curve. My beziers represent sketches as opposed to actual shapes. I don't want the bezier closed, which is what `UIImage.shapeImageWithBezierPath()` does. This last solution is the only one which has actually encapsulated the full curve. All the other solutions either produce fragments or don't show up at all.

The end goal is to create a `CollectionView` with these curves as items in the list, meaning that I ultimately have to put `UIBeziers` into `CollectionViewCells`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a few choices. Probably the best one would involve drawing in a CGContext (using UIBezierPath.cgPath) and then turning that into a CGImage. From there it's very simple to make a UIImage, but you may not need to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want `UIImage` (which you can use with `UIImageView`), you can use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`:

```
private func image(with path: UIBezierPath, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { _ in
        UIColor.blue.setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = 2
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

That was introduced in iOS 10. If you need to support earlier iOS versions, you can use the `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`:

```
private func image(with path: UIBezierPath, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    UIColor.blue.setStroke()
    path.lineWidth = 2
    path.stroke()
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can bypass the `UIImage` if you want, and just define a `UIView` subclass with a `CAShapeLayer`:

```
@IBDesignable
class ShapeView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var lineWidth:   CGFloat = 1   { didSet { shapeLayer.lineWidth   = lineWidth } }
    @IBInspectable var strokeColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 1)  { didSet { shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor } }
    @IBInspectable var fillColor:   UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)  { didSet { shapeLayer.fillColor   = fillColor.cgColor } }

    var path:  UIBezierPath? { didSet { shapeLayer.path = path?.cgPath } }

    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        configure()
    }

    /// Add and configure the view.
    ///
    /// Add and configure shape.

    private func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        shapeLayer.strokeColor = self.strokeColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor   = self.fillColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth   = self.lineWidth
    }

    // just add some path so if you used this in IB, you'll see something

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth / 2, dy: lineWidth / 2)).cgPath
    }

}
```

Comment: This is working, but I realized what I've been doing wrong. The Bezier path is calculated manually using CGPoints, and the conversion from CGFrames into UIImages is the culprit. So I have some things to fix