# How can I set image for UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set image inside this path (i.e) **I want imageview instead of red colour**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeGsv.png)
**Here is my code**

import UIKit
@IBDesignable

class diagonalviewprofile: UIView {

```
@IBInspectable var color : UIColor? = UIColor.red {
    didSet {
        //            self.layer.backgroundColor = self.color?.cgColor
        
 

    }

}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

}

// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    //get the size of the view
    let size = self.bounds.size
    //get 4 points for the shape layer
    let p1 = self.bounds.origin
    let p2 = CGPoint(x: p1.x + size.width, y: p1.y)
    let p3 = CGPoint(x: p2.x, y: size.height - 150)
    let p4 = CGPoint(x: p1.x, y: size.height - 30)

    //create the path
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: p1)
    path.addLine(to: p2)
    path.addLine(to: p3)
    path.addLine(to: p4)
    path.close()
    (color ?? UIColor.red).set()
    path.fill()

}
```

}

I want to set image inside this path (i.e) **I want imageview instead of red colour**

Comment: Look into masking: https://medium.com/@peteliev/layer-masking-for-beginners-c18a0a10743

Comment: Can you please try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42824066/11647876)

Comment: Where i can add image name on this @KhyatiModi

Comment: There is one more [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49853457/11647876) available, you must try

Answer (score 0):

You can set image like:

// get an image of the graphics context

`let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!`